# Combo Box that searches 2 columns in a table and filters all rows that match either column

Tags: excel, vba, datatable, combobox, autofilter

Please bear with me, I'm very new the VBA using excel though I have some experience using it for access. I am trying to create a combo box and using VBA I want that box to filter my table if the combo box selection matches either of the two columns. Basically I have a table of projects. each project has a lead and a secondary person assigned to it. I want to be able to select a name from the combo box (or if there is a better way to do it) and show all the projects that the name is associated with.

I have created a combo box with a targe range that is on a sepearte tab. Asside from that I could not figure out how to the autofilter funcition to work.

Comment: New and already asking for the impossible. `AutoFilter` can't do it. Of course, there are other possibilities. Why don't you share the code you have tried so we can build on it? Also, add some relevant sample data as text and a screenshot so we can better understand where the data is located. Also, share if you want to copy the data or just look at it. In the latter case, you can basically loop through the rows and opt for 1.) using `Autofilter` on a column with unique values (if there is one) by writing the unique values to an array. or for 2.) just hiding the undesired rows.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured out how to accomplish this, though open to ideas on how to improve it. I created a hidden column that concatenates the 2 columns I want to filter against. I then created a listbox and 2 checkboxes to select the name I want to filter along with some combination of that name appearing in the first column, the 2nd, or either. I added the code to sub for any changes in the listbox or either checkbox.

Is there a way to select multiple names in the listbox so I can filter more than one person. I do see how I would run into problems in the concatenated column though.

```
Dim NameSelect As String

On Error Resume Next

NameSelect = NameList.Value

If PrimaryCheck = False And SecondaryCheck = False Then
    Sheets("Weekly Update").ListObjects("tblPipeline").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Exit Sub
ElseIf PrimaryCheck = True And SecondaryCheck = False Then
    Sheets("Weekly Update").ListObjects("tblPipeline").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Sheets("Weekly Update").ListObjects("tblPipeline").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="*" & NameSelect & "*"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Exit Sub
ElseIf PrimaryCheck = False And SecondaryCheck = True Then
    Sheets("Weekly Update").ListObjects("tblPipeline").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Sheets("Weekly Update").ListObjects("tblPipeline").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*" & NameSelect & "*"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Exit Sub
ElseIf PrimaryCheck = True And SecondaryCheck = True Then
    Sheets("Weekly Update").ListObjects("tblPipeline").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Sheets("Weekly Update").ListObjects("tblPipeline").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="*" & NameSelect & "*"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: I also moved the repeating code under each if and elseif statement (ShowAllData and ScrollRow) in front of the if-elseif statement so they no longer need to repeat. Not sure why I didnt write it that way to begin.